# Automation in BASH- Creating thing in AWS-IoT. How can I retrieve the thingId after its creation?

Tags: bash, automation, aws-cli, aws-iot

This is when we create a thing in AWS in a BASH script.
It is working well but I would like to retrieve the thing_ID and store it in a variable.

Here is the bash code that creates the thing. It is the first call of mosquito `mosquitto_pub --cafile root.cert --cert deviceCertAndCACert.crt --key deviceCert.key -h xxxxx.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -t foo/bar -I anyclientID --tls-version tlsv1.2 -m "Hello" -d` but in the first connection it only returns:

```
Client anyclientID18351 sending CONNECT
Error: The connection was lost.
```

How could I retrieve the thing_Id after its creation?

This is the code:

```
openssl genrsa -out deviceCert.key 2048
openssl req -new -key deviceCert.key -out deviceCert.csr -subj "/C=CA/ST=ON/L=NY/O=SC/OU=DG/CN=EX"
openssl x509 -req -in deviceCert.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out deviceCert.crt -days 365 -sha256
cat deviceCert.crt rootCA.pem > deviceCertAndCACert.crt
wget https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem
mv VeriSign-Class\ 3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem root.cert
mosquitto_pub --cafile root.cert --cert deviceCertAndCACert.crt --key deviceCert.key -h xxxxx.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -t foo/bar -I anyclientID --tls-version tlsv1.2 -m "Hello" -d
mosquitto_pub --cafile root.cert --cert deviceCertAndCACert.crt --key deviceCert.key -h xxxxx.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -t foo/bar -I anyclientID --tls-version tlsv1.2 -m "Thing $i is Working" -d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the thing than you can use the [describe-thing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/describe-thing.html) command in the CLI.

`aws iot describe-thing --thing-name ENTER_THING_NAME_HERE`

response:

```
{
    "defaultClientId": "anyclientID",
    "thingName": "THING_NAME",
    "thingId": "40da2e73-c6af-406e-b415-15acae538797",
    "thingArn": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:123456789012:thing/THING_NAME",
    "thingTypeName": "LightBulb",
    "attributes": {
        "model": "123",
        "wattage": "75"
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

Comment: the code that creates the thing and attach certificates is this one `mosquitto_pub --cafile root.cert --cert deviceCertAndCACert.crt --key deviceCert.key -h xxxxx.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -t foo/bar -I anyclientID --tls-version tlsv1.2 -m "Hello" -d` the first connection with the brocker. Unfortunately this code returns (for the first time) an error,  this is when AWS creates the thing. I can't retrieve the name of the created thing.

Comment: do you have any indication about the thing at all? are there any other things except for this one? perhaps you can list all the things and then filter them out with some logic

Comment: at the end of the day I had to move my logic to a lambda (with NodeJS) that does the same task. Task is create things, activate them and return the privateKey and certificate for each thing created. But now I can't attach the thing to a CA root certificate that I have created in AWS-iot.